# Extract time out of a date and timestamp

Tags: r

I have a vector of timestamps and just wish to get the hour and minute out, for example what I have looks like; 2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00 and what I want it to become is 18:43 if possible. I thought about splitting it up and removing everything before and after the T and + (inclusive) but wasnt quite sure how that was done using a gsub, this would also still leave the seconds which i dont want here

```
tstamps
"2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00"     "2023-03-06T18:44:45.547+00:00" "2023-03-06T18:47:04.643+00:00"
```

Comment: `sub(".*T(\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*",'\\1','2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00')`

Answer (score 2):

you can use lubridate and dplyr packages for that:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(datetime = c("2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00", "2023-03-06T12:30:00+00:00"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(time = format(ymd_hms(datetime), "%H:%M"))
df
```

which will return:

```
                   datetime  time
1 2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00 18:43
2 2023-03-06T12:30:00+00:00 12:30
```

Answer (score 0):

After `sub` away the colons in offset, we can use `strptime()`.

```
strftime(strptime(sub('(.*):(.*)', '\\1\\2', x), '%FT%H:%M:%OS%z', tz='GMT'), '%H:%M')
# [1] "18:43" "18:44" "18:47"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c('2023-03-06T18:43:52+00:00', '2023-03-06T18:44:45.547+00:00', '2023-03-06T18:47:04.643+00:00')
```